# How to overlap colors

Tags: color, color-management

I have a requirement to overlap the colors so that they look a bit appealing. For now they can be seen with clear boundary between them. Please suggest how can I overlap the colors

[image]

Comment: You probably should not be using different materials across your mesh, but a gradient texture instead.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51487/how-to-change-color-along-a-curve

Answer (score 1):

You could use vertex colors.

Or you could do the fading by hand, you'd need to make an object for each color (or duplicate the mesh) and then move the UVs on an alpha texuture so you get gradients where you want them.

Or of course you can use cycles:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Well created the mixture of the colors, how to apply this now?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-_mwX_vWUT4Q1FsbldfQWppUWc

Comment: try plugging the geometry or the UV-coordinates into the mix factor, good idea!

Comment: Im editing my answer to show some options